# ECS randomly terminates instances and starts again: Error: No Container Instances were found in your cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

So I have an ECS cluster with 1 EC2.

Every other day the EC2 instance is terminated and starts again another EC2 instance. So dumb.

In the service logs I see:  `service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container Instances were found in your cluster. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section.`

I think is because the cluster might not be able to reach the instance and thinks is gone.

How could I prevent this from happening?

At the moment I'm using a hack to use the instance. I associate the EC2 to an elastic IP so I can access it from my domain. But when it terminates, the new instance is not associated to that IP anymore, so everything is broken.

Any solutions on how to fix this?

Edit:

**Auto scalling activity**

- At 2020-08-30T22:10:02Z an instance was taken out of service in response to a EC2 instance status checks failure.
- At 2020-08-30T22:10:23Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1.

Looks like I get: StatusCheckFailed_Instance & StatusCheckFailed error.

**Edit 2:** seems like I run out of cpu cycles, then instance becomes very slow and is terminated. So if it happens please check the charts in https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1

[image]

So here my ec2 instance was not responding or was very slow.

Comment: If you're using ECS with EC2 there must be an auto-scaling group created for that cluster. Can you check the reason behind the EC2 termination in the auto-scaling group's activity logs and see what's going wrong with the instances. Additionally you can use an ALB along with dynamic port mapping in ECS which will reduce your manual efforts.

Comment: I see in activity this: "At 2020-08-30T22:10:02Z an instance was taken out of service in response to a EC2 instance status checks failure."

Comment: Yes, using a load balancer would be ideal, but I try to avoid a load balancer because of the costs. Do you know how to create a copy of the EC2 created by auto scaling so it won't be managed by auto scaling anymore? If I create the EC2 instance manually keeps saying the daemon is out of date and doesn't connect to my cluster.